# Using alloc, init in ARC enabled projects

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, init, alloc

Actually I am working on a project with `ARC` enabled. I know using `alloc` and `init` is taking `ownership` of the object. I know, If I create a string like this

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Something"];
```

then I need to `release` the `myString` on myself. **What If I am using ARC enabled? I cannot release on myself. So will it create a leak? Or should I don't create object like this?**

I can create a string like below code too.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something"];
```

**But which type I need to use exactly for ARC enabled project ? What will happen if I use first type?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use ARC, all the necessary `release` calls will be added for you when you compile. It will not leak.

The difference between

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Something"];
```

and

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something"];
```

is that the first one will automatically released after the last reference to `myString` in that block, while the second one is an autoreleased instance that will only be released at the end of the run loop. It's not a big difference, but if you're using a lot of objects, try to avoid autoreleased ones to keep memory usage low.

Comment: If I am using large number of temporary objects, I need to use the first way. Right??

Comment: It would be a better choice, yes. Or, you could also use an `@autorelease{}` pool to release autoreleased objects before the end of the run loop. Check out the WWDC videos about ARC.

Comment: ok. I understood. One more doubt. Instead of using objects, If I am using lot of temporary primitive type variables? still autorelease pool will release those variables??

Comment: No. Objective-C memory management (both manual and ARC) only manages memory for Objective-C objects. Primitive types are different. They are allocated on the stack and come and go as functions are called and return. If you `malloc` primitive pointers on the heap, you have to `free` them yourself, but that's completely independent from releasing objects in Obj-C.

Comment: ok ok I get it. I thought those primitive types also make too much memory. Now I get it. They are not reference counting. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: The second pattern may not produce an autoreleased object as the compiler might optimize that pattern to eliminate the autorelease.  It would do so, for example, if NSString were compiled with ARC enabled.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have a source? Not that I don't believe you.

Answer (score 1):

ARC takes care of the memory management, so no you don't need to worry about calling `release` on your `myString` variable, ARC will do that for you. Also as a suggestion I would recommend using convenience methods to create your object such as

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something"];`

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to set the string pointer to nil to release it.
You can also do the same things that you would be able to do without ARC, but with the advantage that if you don't explicitly do anything, the ARC will manage (almost) everything for you.

So to release it you set it to nil, let's see what else you could do:

```
    NSString* str= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String: "Hello"];
    // here the retain count of str is 1
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* string= str;
    // again 1 because string is __unsafe_unretained
    void* data= (__bridge_retained void*) string;
    // data retains the string, so the retain count is to 2
    // This is useful in the case that you have to pass an objective-c object
    // through a void pointer.You could also say NSString* data= string;
    str=nil;
    // Here the retain count of str is 1
    NSLog(@"%@",(__bridge NSString*)data);
```

**UPDATE**

Here's why sometimes you don't notice that an object is released:

```
    NSString* str= [[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"hey"];
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* str2=str;
    str=nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",str2);
```

In this case str=[[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"hey"] is equal to str=@"hey", with the difference that str is autoreleased and not released.But the compiler optimizes the code in str=@"hello", so if you are inside an autorelease block you won't have any problem, str2 will be printed correctly.
That's why I used initWithUTF8String, to avoid that compiler optimization.

Comment: I don't think setting nil is gonna release the object. For instance If I create an object like this **NSString *myString = nil;** is it getting released so??

Comment: Yes it does.Without ARC if you try to release a nil object it doesn't create problems, nil targered actions are ignored.I don't known how the ARC is implemented, maybe it sends a nil targered release message, or maybe it does in some other way.